# Finite State Machine user input tree

Tags: finite-state-machine

I'm drawing a Finite State Machine (which I'll have to implement later on) which is semi-automatic, i.e. some transitions require user input, some are decided on internal value.

The problem is that some transitions are decision trees with several possible transitions. How should I draw such cases?  I am considering drawing something like submachine, representing the decision tree, but maybe there is some another more standard approach?

Decision trees apply only to user input. Decision tree is a series of yes/no questions and every answer might branch-off into another question or transition. There are no "empty" branches - transition will happen, though some transitions are duplicated, i.e. several decision paths may lead to the same transition.
The decision tree is at most 5 levels deep, therefore listing every combination of criteria on a transition is an overkill.

Comment: What factors decide which transition you take from the tree?

Comment: @sydan I've complemented my question with decision tree information

Comment: Is is possible that each different point along a branch of the decision tree is simply another state? If you're suffering from the usual 'state explosion' issue of FSMs I would urge you to investigate Hierarchically State Machines: http://aigamedev.com/open/article/hfsm-gist/ as a possible solution. They can be a bit of a drudge at first but open up much strong solutions in the future.

Comment: I believe not. The FSM in question describes a control unit, that measures some parameters of a system. One transition requires visual inspection by a user and selection of a further transition. User intervention is required in other cases, but that I represent as a simple value transition. As I mention in my question, the transition in question has a ruleset for transition that is too complex to represent as a logical expression. This IS part of a hierarchical FSM :)

Comment: My current approach involves a pseudo-state in which I display the transition algorithm (bunch of conditionals). Is this proper approach?

Comment: I'm trying to visualize how the questioning of the operator fits with the automatic part of the FSM...  The questioning is initiated by the FSM, so it synchronous with the FSM, right?  Does the questions depend on answers to previous questions?  In how many places in the state machine does questioning occur (one, more that one place)?